# How can I select championship winners in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing a couple of exercises in preparation for my exams, and I stumbled upon a problem in one concerning SQL. I have a database with information about Formula 1 drivers, races, and results.

- In the 'drivers' table, there are driver_id, last_name, first_name, country columns.
- Races table: race_id, season, grand_prix.
- Results table: driver_id, points, race_id.

I am trying to select first and last names of championship winners from years 2000, 2006, 2012, along with the sum of their points in years where they won. 
I ran the following query, which gives me the sum of points for each driver in each year, but I don't know how to only get the top ones from each year.

```
SELECT season, first_name, last_name, SUM(points)
FROM (drivers JOIN results ON drivers.driver_id = results.driver_id)
JOIN races ON races.race_id = results.race_id
WHERE season IN(2000, 2006, 2012)
GROUP BY season, first_name, last_name;
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: It's MySQL version 8.0

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First join `Results` to `Races` and aggregate to get the total points of drivers for each season and with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function get the top 1 driver.
Then join to `Drivers` to get the driver's name:

```
SELECT g.season, d.last_name, d.first_name, g.points 
FROM (
  SELECT r.season, t.driver_id, SUM(t.points) points,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.season ORDER BY SUM(t.points) DESC) rn 
  FROM Results t INNER JOIN Races r
  ON t.race_id = r.race_id
  WHERE r.season IN (2000, 2006, 2012)
  GROUP BY r.season, t.driver_id
) g INNER JOIN Drivers d
ON d.driver_id = g.driver_id AND g.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If i didnt misunderstood your question, you should try this :

```
SELECT t.season, t.first_name, t.last_name, t.points
FROM    (
        SELECT  seasons
        FROM (drivers JOIN results ON drivers.driver_id = results.driver_id)
        JOIN races ON races.race_id = results.race_id
        ) a
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT b.season, b.first_name, b.last_name, SUM(c.points) AS points
        FROM (drivers b JOIN results c ON drivers.driver_id = results.driver_id) 
        JOIN races ON races.race_id = results.race_id
        WHERE season IN(2000, 2006, 2012) AND a.seasons = b.season
        ORDER BY points DESC
        LIMIT 1
        ) t
```

Comment: Your query still returns all of the drivers, I'd like to select only the champions from each year 2000, 2006, 2012.

Comment: I Will edit my answer so you can try the code i'll give you